# Highcharts - hidden axis affects performance on redraw

Tags: highcharts

For some time I had performance issues on my chart redraw

E.g. when I tried to redraw a single series on the chart with `setData` function - it redraw all the series

While my debug I found that there's some `isDirty` option on every axis / series, and if it's true on any - the whole chart would be redraw

Then I tried to find which of my elements have that option - and recognized that only one element have it:

```
yAxis.push({
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    visible: false
});
```

That's invisible axis that I use for some additional data on chart

The problem is exactly is on `visible` flag, when it true - everything working fast and fine

When it false - it takes a huge part of performace

I didn't find any mentioning about `isDirty` flag or `visible: false` that affects the performance

So is there any possibility to have a hidden axis w/o `isDirty` flag?

**UPD**
Simple fiddle to show it

https://jsfiddle.net/q6ntdxsy/8/

Change first axis `visible` flag in js section, and `isDirty` would be false

Answer (score 0):

Internal 'isDirty' flag is set to false for each axis after axis render. Invisible axes are never rendered, so this flag will be set to false until the visible status changes. If one axis is dirty, all axes are redrawn.

You can deduce how it works from Highcharts source code: https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js

The solution could be experimental overwrite 'render' method to disable 'isDirty' flag for hidden axes.

```
// Axes
if (chart.hasCartesianSeries) {
    each(axes, function(axis) {
        if (axis.visible) {
            axis.render();

        // Disable 'isDirty' flag for invisible axes
        } else {
            axis.isDirty = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yb4qf1s6/